# How to get better anti-aliasing in blender internal?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, antialiasing

I'm having problem with antialiasing (I think this is the problem...). As you can see from the picture, far object and reflected object are still to rough (see the red arrows).
On the right you can appreciate my antialiasing settings.

Is it a problem of antialiasing? I'm quite new to the blender and the 3D graphics world, so I'd like to understand what is happening.

Thanx in advance !

[image]

**Addition**
Using cycles rendering, I get this:

[image]

Why? I lost all the material settings???

Comment: Try using cycles? The reflection probably just needs more samples, but not sure what you  can do about the far away sphere.

Comment: what are cycles? As I said, I'm quite new to blender

Comment: It's another more modern render engine that is developed and bundled with blender. You can use it by selecting *Cycles* in the dropdown at the top of the screen which is currently set to *Blender Render*. Also note that the latest version of blender is 2.74, 2.69 is a bit old now..

Comment: Thanks man. I used cycles to render but it "loose" the 3dimensionality... I add the new image in the question to better explain...

Comment: It's a completely different engine, and as such it has it's own material system. It's fundamentally different from BI, and materials for the two are incompatible.

Comment: Ok. Some tips about the samples for reflection?

Comment: Come to think of it the samples would only matter if the reflection has gloss amount set to < 1.. Which it looks like might not be the case. My mistake.

Comment: BlenderArtists.org Username VickyM72 knows how to use Blender Render(Internal) better than anyone else that I know of.  Here is a thread she posts to regularly.  You'll have to do some digging but she does have many tips on how to use that render engine on her sketchbook thread.  Unfortunately, she has no obvious presence on this site so here is a link. http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?294117-VickyM72-s-Sketchbook

Comment: I think you were searching for creating (and controlling) blurry reflections in BI rather than antialiasing. Tweaking *Gloss* values in *Mirror* options of the floor material could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think anti-aliasing doesn't have anything to do with this.

I can't see very well, but I think the problem with "rough" reflection in the first image is due to a low amount of reflection raytracing samples. Try increasing the sample amount in the material's "Reflections" tab.

Cycles and Blender Internal rendering engines are defining materials differently, you can't quite switch from one to another every moment and expect to see similar visual results. Setting up object materials for Cycles is a completely different process. When you set up your materials for Blender internal rendered and then switched to Cycles, Blender actually tries to create similar materials, but it's a very basic approximation, this is where there's no reflection on the floor. Also setting up lighting for Cycles is different.

The basic difference is that Blender Internal is a scanline rendering engine, while Cycles is a raytracer. The latter provides much more realism at the cost of much higher computational cost. Blender internal is however very useful for non-realistic renders where advanced light simulation is not needed and we can work with the different tools for "faking" these effects.

For instance: Cycles will calculate how light propagates and reflects from surfaces and what image it will produce when reaching the scene's camera. All the bells and whistles are a part of the simulation of how light behaves in the 3D scene. Blender Internal however uses different tricks to fake these effects like shadow maps, raytraced reflections, bumpmapping, volumetric shadows... in Blender Internal it's all kind of "fake" and approximate and it doesn't look that real when compared to Cycles, which actually is simulating how photons bounce around. The downside of Cycles is the amount of noise you get from fast renders - it's a bit like getting too little exposure time for taking a picture in a dark environment - it's gonna be noisy. The same is with cycles. The more samples you give it to calculate, the less noise you're gonna have (but it can be very time-consuming).